# How to add paper elements to Laravel Angular Material project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, angular-material, paper-elements

I have installed project "[Laravel Angular Material Starter](https://laravel-angular.readme.io/docs)".

Now I want to add some "[Paper elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements)"

I run bower command to include button `bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-button`

But, when I write html code `<paper-button raised>Raised button</paper-button>`

It doesn't work... How to properly include this paper element into project? Maybe I missed some injection for angular app? Or should I add some gulp task, or elixir?

Thanks.

Comment: you have a log of error in the browser console?

Answer (score -1):

Try this example:

[image]

index.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

</head>
<body>

<paper-button raised>Raised button</paper-button>

</body>
</html>
```